Updating table with google docs api using a placeholder as in identifier
I want to update a table in google docs where my number of columns are fixed to 3, a table with 2 rows and 3 columns is already present in the doc, the code has to identify a placeholder {{asas}} to start data entry form a CSV file.
Error:

"Invalid requests[0].insertTableRow: Invalid table start location. Must specify the start index of the table."
after some changes in the code the data is sent to the table but updating is done only in the 1st cell of the table

According to me the code block 'replace placeholder with actual data' is having an issue
def update_table_data(document_id, csv_data):
    service = initialize_docs_api()
    document = service.documents().get(documentId=document_id).execute()
    body = document.get('body', {})
    content = body.get('content', [])
    requests = []

    table_id = None
    for element in content:
        if 'table' in element:
            table = element['table']
            for row in table['tableRows']:
                for cell in row['tableCells']:
                    for content in cell['content']:
                        for element in content['paragraph']['elements']:
                            if 'textRun' in element and '{{asas}}' in element['textRun'].get('content', ''):
                                table_id = element
                                break
                        if table_id:
                            break
                if table_id:
                    break
            if table_id:
                break

    if not table_id:
        print("Table with placeholder '{{asas}}' not found.")
        return

    table_start_index = table_id['startIndex']
    num_rows_needed = len(csv_data)

    # Insert the required number of rows
    for _ in range(num_rows_needed):
        requests.append({
            'insertTableRow': {
                'tableCellLocation': {
                    'tableStartLocation': {
                        'index': table_start_index`your text`
                    },
                    'rowIndex': len(table['tableRows']) - 1  # Insert before the last row
                },
                'insertBelow': True
            }
        })

    # Replace the placeholder with actual data
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_data):
        for j, (key, cell_text) in enumerate(row.items()):
            requests.append({
                'insertText': {
                    'location': {
                        'index': table_start_index + i * len(row) + j  # Calculate the index for the cell
                    },
                    'text': cell_text
                }
            })

    # Execute the requests
    if requests:
        body = {'requests': requests}
        response = service.documents().batchUpd`your text`ate(documentId=document_id, body=body).execute()
        print('Table updated:', response.get('replies'))

I want to update the data in all the rows and columns of the table.

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your situation from your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample value of csv_data, the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

sample data:- data.csv file will be provided by the user number of columns are fixed to 3
col1, col2, col3,
the code must find the placeholder '{{asas}}' and start the data entry from the particular cell.
output:- csv data should be pasted in the table.
